# Can you avoid the pod to be restarted after kubectl attach?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I have an ubuntu image that I use for debugging.
I do `kubectl attach my-app -c my-app -it` and then many `apt-get install` and other configurations I need.

The problem is when I exit `ctrl+c` the pod seems to get restarted and I loose all what I did

Is there a way like `--restart=never` to avoid the container to be recreated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run another shell session `kubectl exec my-app -c my-app -it -- bash` to prepare your container. Alternately, if your pod spec has the following set to true:

```
stdin: true 
tty: true
```

You use the escape sequence Ctrl+P followed by Ctrl+Q to detach from the container after `kubectl attach -it` to the container.